# Get list of deleted onenote notebooks/sections/pages

Tags: onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-api

My appplication periodically sync data with Onenote. If some content is deleted after syncing for the first how I can get list of names of pages/sections/notebooks that are deleted. Currently I am comparing id's of pages/sections/notebooks that are present in my system and one the which I receive from onenote syncing everytime. But this process takes too long and specially if I have large data.

Is there any MS-Graph/OneNote API which can provide me list(id's) of these deleted entities ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no API to retrieve the list of deleted entities, unfortunately. The best way you can achieve this today with the API is to set up webhook integration, keep state on your side and the querying when you receive a webhook notification saying something changed - it looks like you're doing something similar.

If you believe the API should have this functionality, I encourage you to create and upvote an item in uservoice:
https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

Comment: Okay. But this is very basic functionality which is expected to be there. I will definitely put this on user voice forum

Comment: I have asked onenote team to enable webhooks for me but somehow it's not working for me

Comment: Is this for a consumer account (microsoft account) or an organizational account (O365)? We don't support webhooks for organizational accounts. What is not working exactly?

Comment: It's for Microsoft account. I am not sure about the reason as I am waiting for the response from OneNote team. Maybe I can share details with you if you can help with that , it would be great

Comment: App registration got failed at Onenote end got the response from OneNote team. Will seek for your help if it doesn't work. Thank you:)

Comment: I am using microsoft graph endpoints accessing onenote content & azure v2.0 for user authentication. I have registered webhook  and I do receive notifications when I authenticate user using microsoft account but not when I authenticate using azure v2.0. I am not able to understand the reason. can you please help